# Week number that overlaps between 2 years in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to get week number in excel where my week starts from Wednesday to Tuesday. I used `=WEEKkNUM(A1,13)`, where `A1` is a cell that contains a date.

Challenge: When I use weeknum for `1st of JAN 2016`, it shows that the week number is 1 which is wrong. `30th of DEC 2015` is the first week of 53. In other words, when weeknum reaches to first day of a year, it consider it the first week of the year which wrong. Attached screenshot of the issue.

Expectation: `1st-5th of JAN, 2016` must be part of week 53.2015 and not week 01.2016

Please help.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I understand your question well. However, I have a question: If 1/5/2016 (first Tuesday of 2016) is considered part of week 53 in 2015, are you OK with 1/6/2016 (first Wednesday of 2016) to be week **2** of 2016? Or must that be week **1** of 2016?

Comment: Thanks Peter. 6th of JAN 2016 is week 1 of 2016

Answer (score 1):

In M2 enter this formula `=WEEKNUM(A3,13)-1`, then from M3 enter this formula `=IF(WEEKNUM(A3,13)=1,M2,WEEKNUM(A3,13)-1)` and drag it to the bottom. You will have 52 weeks instead of 53, which is logical since you do not have cross weeks.

2015 crossing.
[image]

2016 crossing.

[image]

Comment: 2015 is 53 weeks :(

Comment: Actually, it is not...if you do not count cross week (first week of 2015, which has 6 days)...

Answer (score 1):

Correct formula is =ISOWEEKNUM(A2-2)

Comment: As per my comment on my answer, you can get the same result with simple =ISOWEEKNUM(A2-2)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
= MOD(WEEKNUM(A1,13)-IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1),13)>1,1,0)-1,52)+1
```

Comment: @KhaderAbdelrahman Correct. If the start and end of the year is defined as the first Wednesday in the year, it is impossible to have more than (or less than) 52 weeks.

Comment: @KhaderAbdelrahman This is why I specifically asked you if the first week of the year should be considered week 1 or week 2. If you want to keep 53, then your weeks would go from 2 to 53 instead of 1 to 52.

Comment: How can we create formula that doesn't check if the first day of the year is Wednesday or not? I believe we can use ISOWEEKNUM function because it can till if the year is 53 weeks but not sure how. What do you think?

Comment: @Peter >`If the start and end of the year is defined as the first Wednesday in the year, it is impossible to have more than (or less than) 52 weeks` - I don't think that's true. First Wednesday of 2020 is 1st Jan, first Wednesday of 2021 is 6th Jan hence 2020 has 53 weeks. On average 1 in 5 or 6 years will have 53 weeks

Comment: @barryhoudini Thanks, I realized that shortly after this discussion, haven't had time to look into it to change my formula yet.

Comment: I agree with you about 2015, though, that should be 52 weeks unless I have misunderstood the definition........!

Answer (score 0):

Before the advent of easier formulas to calculate `ISO` week numbers I had a longer method to do so. The advantage of that type of formula is that it's endlessly adaptable based on day start or date start.

This version should give you week number based on week 1 start date being the first Wednesday of the year:

`=INT((A2-WEEKDAY(A2-3)-DATE(YEAR(A2+1-WEEKDAY(A2-3)),1,7))/7)+2`

Using that formula I get the following years with 53 weeks:

2014, 2020, 2025, 2031

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. We are very close to the solution. Still I'm insisting that the end of year 2015 is part of the week 53 since if you check the ISO Week number you will realize that 28th of DEC - 3rd of JAN are week 53.2015. If we want to apply the same logic to my calendar, we have to shift by two days. I tried the following =ISOWEEKNUM(A1+2) but still didn't get the correct solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Guys, I guess I found the solution. The formula is: =IF(INT(WEEKDAY(A2,13))<6,ISOWEEKNUM(A2),ISOWEEKNUM(A2-2)). I validated it and it seems correct. Can someone please check?

Comment: To make 53 weeks in 2015 you need week 1 of 2015 to start on 31st December 2014. The general rule is that week 1 starts on first Wed on or after 31st December. If you are happy with that then your formula works perfectly!

Comment: ....also this formula will give the same result - `=ISOWEEKNUM(A2-2)` or equivalent `=WEEKNUM(A2-2,21)`